# Tizen 4.0 Get proxy bypass value in a Web Application

Tags: web, proxy, tizen, bypass

Im trying to get that value previously configured on the device(see the image bellow), Im able to get all the other 4 data even the pwd with **b2bapis.b2bcontrol.getProxyserverInfo();** but the bypass(excluder) value Im not able, According with the docs I have also tried with the method **tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue** and the param **NET_PROXY_NETWORK** but it returns that is not supported(the doc tells that is supported since v3.0 and Im using v4.0), I dont even know if with this Im going to be able to get the value I want, does anyone know how can I get that value?

My config.xml also contains:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.net_proxy"/>
```

And all **network privileges**

This is the value that I need:

[image: This is the value that I need]

EDIT:
The API version is 4.0 instead 4.5 (I've already edited in the original post)

Comment: I don't know exact answer to your question, but let me explain to you a concept of 'support version'. NetProxy is supported on Tizen since 3.0, but this is a conditional feature and can be not supported on your device even the version is higher than 3.0. You can check if it is supported with tizen.systeminfo.getCapability("http://tizen.org/feature/network.net_proxy")  (as it is described on https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/mobile/tizen/systeminfo.html). Anyway, the interface of SystemInfoNetProxyNetwork does not include information you need, so it is a dead-end.

Comment: Also maybe it is worth checking once again, if your Tizen version is really 4.5. As I can see here - https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/index.html API list does not include 4.5 version, only 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5 and so on.

Comment: Thank you 15kokos, I've already checked with tizen.systeminfo.getCapability("tizen.org/feature/network.net_proxy") getting the same result: "NotSupportedError" with the message "Value for given key was not found", but as you said, if does not include the value its a dead-end, also: my mistake, you are right the API version is 4.0, it is getting me crazy to obtain that value